# System Recovery From an External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, system-recovery

I created a Disk Image to my external hard drive but cannot seem to restore from it. Most explainations seem to only talk about CDs or DVDs. I'm running Windows 7 if that makes any difference. My hard drive is formatted to NTFS. Would burning the image onto a CD be easier? I've also gone to Repair My Computer through the Recovery section which then causes me to restart but I end up with the message 
`The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible`. I'm desperate to get this working, any help or thoughts would be much appreciated.

This is the contents of the disk image on my HD
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a System Recovery disk first.  Since you can get into Windows, you can do this by typing "System Recovery" into the search box, which should get you the tool --

[image: Create system recovery disk]

Once you have a System Recovery disk, boot from that & choose "System Image Recovery", and select the image from your external disk.
[image: System image choice]

It may be that the external drive is disrupting the drive letter sequence when Windows is up, but should work if you boot from the System Recovery CD you make -- i.e. set the BIOS to boot from CD first.  Even if it doesn't find the system image automatically, you can still browse to it on the external drive.

Great tutorial at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7702/restoring-windows-7-from-an-image-backup/ with lots of screenshots.